# Как задать возможность кикать участников боту?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, python-3.8

Здраствуйте, я хочу научить бота выполнять команду кика, как это сделать? Могу написать примерную команду

kick @ТегЮзера

Comment: И как Вы хотите кикать, если у пользователя нет юзернейма?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кикать по юзернейму идея не очень, лучше всего ответом на сообщение. Команда будет выглядеть примерно так:

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=["kick"])
def kick_user_handler(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    
    if message.type not in ("group", "supergroup"):
        # Команда используется не в чате
        return None

    member = bot.get_chat_member(chat_id, message.from_user.id)
    if not member.can_restrict_members:
        # У пользователя нет прав банить пользователя
        return None

    if message.reply_to_message is None:
        # Команда используется не ответом на сообщение
        return bot.reply_to(message, "Эту команду нужно использовать ответом на сообщение...")

    bot.ban_chat_member(chat_id, message.reply_to_message.from_user.id, 3600)
```

Вместо 3600 установите свою длительность.

Comment: Окей, я понял. Спасибо!